# Unit testing simple Tree structure manipulations

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tree, c#-3.0, pattern-matching

Given a very simple structure such as this:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<TreeNode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

*`TreeNode` may have other properties.*

And when used in the following manner:

```
var tree = new List<TreeNode>(); //no root node
```

If I perform add/update/remove operations on the tree based on certain criteria.  For example, removal of a node based on one or more of the *other properties* I mentioned above, I'd like to compare the tree graph before and after the changes and then via unit tests verify some of the follow:

- Tree remains unchanged
- Specified nodes are removed
- Specified nodes are added
- Specified nodes are updated
- The 3 above whilst also verifying that the rest of the tree is unchanged.

Ideally, I'd throw an expection listing the nodes that were not found, not expected etc.  However, at this stage I'd be happy with a true/false to my check.

Are there any known patterns/alogorithms existing projects that would help with this?

I am happy for pseudo-code or examples in other languages as long as they don't rely on features I can't replicate in .NET.

My tree is unlikely to get to more than 7 or 8 levels deep and no more than a hundred nodes in total as it will be test data so brute force looping is fine and performance isn't a consideration at this time.

I'm really looking for tips, tricks, advice, code on how to approach this.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

When I did unit tests for tree structures, I simply built an ad-hoc tree of already known structure, execute operations on it and verified that the changes are exactly the ones I expected, a very simple but usable method, if you create good test cases.

Regardless my experience, you may think of some recursive comparison methods for tree nodes that may return a list of children nodes which are different. So the basic idea is to maintain two equal trees, perform operation on one of them, then check what was changed.

If you don't have any UI that shows the tree, I'd also recommend to make visualizations of a tree, using http://www.graphviz.org/ , you may generate pictures of your tree before and after some operation, so you will see how whole structure was changed(not usable for unit tests, but anyway).

And the last thing, I suggest to have a root node, it will simplify your recursive algorithms. If you don't have root, because of some requirments for UI or so, you may modify that part to simply ignore the root.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a function that get the string representation of the tree and simply compare 2 string representations instead of comparing 2 trees 
I did that earlier this week 
example function (swift)

```
 public var description: String {
        var s = "\(value)"
        if !children.isEmpty {
            s += " {" + children.map { "\($0.description)"}.joined(separator: ", ") + "}"
        }
        return s
    }
```

You can test it like this

```
XCTAssert ( tree.description == "beverages {hot {tea {black, green, chai}, coffee, cocoa}, cold {soda {ginger ale, bitter lemon}, milk}}");
```